# Admin User and Password for Netbeans created Glassfish domains?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

When I create a “development” glassfish (3.1) domain with netbeans (6.9) then no passwords are needed. Everything works magically.

Nice on the first glance. Until you actually need to know the admin user and password.

The normal combination **admin** / **adminadmin** does not actually work.

Also the normal master password **changeit** won't get me anywhere.

Does anybody knows which credentials netbeans uses when creating a glassfish domain?

Of course I tried to create a domain using asadmin. But then NetBeans does not like these domains all that much, i.e. NetBeans starts to ask for passwords, automatic start of domain does not work any more. Trouble without end.

**Update 1:**

I tried to use empty passwords as suggested but this does not work either:

```
Authentication failed for user: admin
with password from password file: …\Domain.properties
(Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
Command create-file-user failed.
```

Am I between the hard rock and the deep blue sea here? NetBeans created domains don't work with command-line and command-line created domains don't work with netbeans?

Comment: Can you provide more details about 'you actually need to know the passowrd'?

Comment: in the curretnt case I want to use asadmin.bat to create non privileged test users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself (again - when will I finally get my self learner badge?)

The problem is that the admin user is:

```
--user anonymous
```

no where documented. I only found it in the  `config/admin-keyfile`. The password then is indeed empty as vkraemer suggested:

```
AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: On a related note, there is a bug under Netbeans 7.1 + JDK7 that prevents logins. See http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206930

Comment: It is a little bit documented. When you create a new domain in Netbeans (by creating a new Glassfish server) you so the following lines:                  No domain initializers found, bypassing customization step
Domain personal_domain_1 created.
Domain personal_domain_1 admin port is 4848.
Domain personal_domain_1 allows admin login as user "anonymous" with no password.
Command create-domain executed successfully.

Comment: Where did you find `config/admin-keyfile`?

Answer (score 7):

Most obvious answer missing? Netbeans - > Services - > Glassfish -> Properties -> Password show?

Answer (score 2):

If you use NetBeans to create a development domain, it does not have a password. Sending one to the various commands will cause problems.

Comment: Which leaves me with the question on how to **not** send a password. asadmin will tell me to set AS_XXXX_PASSWORD if not presented with a password. I can try AS_XXXX_PASSWORD= for starters and see how that works.

Comment: Empty passwords in the password property file do not work as expected. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, login to the Administration Console using admin/adminadmin and then change the password. After that, you will be able to connect from Netbeans. I did that with Netbeans 8.

Answer (score 0):

Remove username, password in development environment.