# GlassFish 3 Authentication Failed

Tags: java, glassfish

I worked with `GlassFish` so much, now when i try to start `GlassFish` and when i set username and password, i get **Authentication Failed** :

[image: Authentication Failed]

- I tryed with another glassfish, and another version `3.1.2.1` and `3.1.2`, and `Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2`
- I delete my domain and i create it again many times, but i get the same problem,
- I create a domain without password, but still ask for the password!!
- I use `jdk1.7.0`.

I think the problem in my windows?

Someone have an idea about this problem, and how to solve it?

**Log**

```
[#|2016-11-06T08:54:21.111+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.ssl.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.impl|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC5054: Certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23741889829347261660812437366387754385443431973861114865490414153884050331745811968523116847625570146592736935209718565296053386842135985534863157983128812774162998053673746470782252407673402238146869994438729551246768368782318393878374421033907597162218758024581735139682087126982809511479059100617027892880227587855877479432885604404402435662802390484099065871430585284534529627347717530352189612077130606642676951640071336717026459037542552927905851171460589361570392199748753414855675665635003335769915908187224347232807336022456537328962095005323382940080676931822787496212635993279098588863972868266229522169377
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Aug 14 15:50:00 GMT+01:00 1998,
               To: Thu Aug 15 00:59:00 GMT+01:00 2013]
  Issuer: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    01b6]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 76 0A 49 21 38 4C 9F DE   F8 C4 49 C7 71 71 91 9D  v.I!8L....I.qq..
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.2.840.113763.1.2.1.3]
[]  ]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:5
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 41 3A D4 18 5B DA B8 DE   21 1C E1 8E 09 E5 F1 68  A:..[...!......h
0010: 34 FF DE 96 F4 07 F5 A7   3C F3 AC 4A B1 9B FA 92  4.......<..J....
0020: FA 9B ED E6 32 21 AA 4A   76 C5 DC 4F 38 E5 DF D5  ....2!.Jv..O8...
0030: 86 E4 D5 C8 76 7D 98 D7   B1 CD 8F 4D B5 91 23 6C  ....v......M..#l
0040: 8B 8A EB EA 7C EF 14 94   C4 C6 F0 1F 4A 2D 32 71  ............J-2q
0050: 63 2B 63 91 26 02 09 B6   80 1D ED E2 CC B8 7F DB  c+c.&...........
0060: 87 63 C8 E1 D0 6C 26 B1   35 1D 40 66 10 1B CD 95  .c...l&.5.@f....
0070: 54 18 33 61 EC 13 4F DA   13 F7 99 AF 3E D0 CF 8E  T.3a..O.....>...
0080: A6 72 A2 B3 C3 05 9A C9   27 7D 92 CC 7E 52 8D B3  .r......'....R..
0090: AB 70 6D 9E 89 9F 4D EB   1A 75 C2 98 AA D5 02 16  .pm...M..u......
00A0: D7 0C 8A BF 25 E4 EB 2D   BC 98 E9 58 38 19 7C B9  ....%..-...X8...
00B0: 37 FE DB E2 99 08 73 06   C7 97 83 6A 7D 10 01 2F  7.....s....j.../
00C0: 32 B9 17 05 4A 65 E6 2F   CE BE 5E 53 A6 82 E9 9A  2...Je./..^S....
00D0: 53 0A 84 74 2D 83 CA C8   94 16 76 5F 94 61 28 F0  S..t-.....v_.a(.
00E0: 85 A7 39 BB D7 8B D9 A8   B2 13 1D 54 09 34 24 7D  ..9........T.4$.
00F0: 20 81 7D 66 7E A2 90 74   5C 10 C6 BD EC AB 1B C2   ..f...t\.......

]|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:54:29.913+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:54:31.147+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.ssl.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.impl|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC5054: Certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23741889829347261660812437366387754385443431973861114865490414153884050331745811968523116847625570146592736935209718565296053386842135985534863157983128812774162998053673746470782252407673402238146869994438729551246768368782318393878374421033907597162218758024581735139682087126982809511479059100617027892880227587855877479432885604404402435662802390484099065871430585284534529627347717530352189612077130606642676951640071336717026459037542552927905851171460589361570392199748753414855675665635003335769915908187224347232807336022456537328962095005323382940080676931822787496212635993279098588863972868266229522169377
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Aug 14 15:50:00 GMT+01:00 1998,
               To: Thu Aug 15 00:59:00 GMT+01:00 2013]
  Issuer: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    01b6]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 76 0A 49 21 38 4C 9F DE   F8 C4 49 C7 71 71 91 9D  v.I!8L....I.qq..
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.2.840.113763.1.2.1.3]
[]  ]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:5
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 41 3A D4 18 5B DA B8 DE   21 1C E1 8E 09 E5 F1 68  A:..[...!......h
0010: 34 FF DE 96 F4 07 F5 A7   3C F3 AC 4A B1 9B FA 92  4.......<..J....
0020: FA 9B ED E6 32 21 AA 4A   76 C5 DC 4F 38 E5 DF D5  ....2!.Jv..O8...
0030: 86 E4 D5 C8 76 7D 98 D7   B1 CD 8F 4D B5 91 23 6C  ....v......M..#l
0040: 8B 8A EB EA 7C EF 14 94   C4 C6 F0 1F 4A 2D 32 71  ............J-2q
0050: 63 2B 63 91 26 02 09 B6   80 1D ED E2 CC B8 7F DB  c+c.&...........
0060: 87 63 C8 E1 D0 6C 26 B1   35 1D 40 66 10 1B CD 95  .c...l&.5.@f....
0070: 54 18 33 61 EC 13 4F DA   13 F7 99 AF 3E D0 CF 8E  T.3a..O.....>...
0080: A6 72 A2 B3 C3 05 9A C9   27 7D 92 CC 7E 52 8D B3  .r......'....R..
0090: AB 70 6D 9E 89 9F 4D EB   1A 75 C2 98 AA D5 02 16  .pm...M..u......
00A0: D7 0C 8A BF 25 E4 EB 2D   BC 98 E9 58 38 19 7C B9  ....%..-...X8...
00B0: 37 FE DB E2 99 08 73 06   C7 97 83 6A 7D 10 01 2F  7.....s....j.../
00C0: 32 B9 17 05 4A 65 E6 2F   CE BE 5E 53 A6 82 E9 9A  2...Je./..^S....
00D0: 53 0A 84 74 2D 83 CA C8   94 16 76 5F 94 61 28 F0  S..t-.....v_.a(.
00E0: 85 A7 39 BB D7 8B D9 A8   B2 13 1D 54 09 34 24 7D  ..9........T.4$.
00F0: 20 81 7D 66 7E A2 90 74   5C 10 C6 BD EC AB 1B C2   ..f...t\.......

]|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:54:31.149+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:54:32.613+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Unsupported Response Format: 'text/html; charset=utf-8'!|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.001+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.jmx.org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX007: Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: { name = system, Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = 0.0.0.0, Port = 8686, AcceptAll = false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = false} having exception java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng:8686/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server]|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.004+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng:8686/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:827)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.start(RMIConnectorStarter.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:328)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.rebind(GenericURLContext.java:249)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:642)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:427)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:632)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:157)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:128)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 13 more
|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.004+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:827)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.004+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:432)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.004+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.start(RMIConnectorStarter.java:301)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.005+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:287)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.005+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:328)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.005+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server]|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.005+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:159)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.006+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.rebind(GenericURLContext.java:249)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.006+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.006+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.006+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:642)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.006+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:427)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.007+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| ... 3 more|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.007+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: HISSAB-VDI15.grp-sonelgaz.sng; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.007+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:632)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.007+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.008+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.008+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.008+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.008+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:157)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.009+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| ... 8 more|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.009+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.009+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:128)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.009+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:459)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.010+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.010+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.010+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.010+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.010+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.011+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.011+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:01.011+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| ... 13 more|#]

[#|2016-11-06T08:55:02.438+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|null|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Domain Pinged: stable.glassfish.org|#]
```

Comment: Isn't the default user *admin* and pass *admin*?

Comment: Thank you @CGec, i tryed to create a domain with another username and password, but same problem, is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem, then look in the `server.log` to see what errors are there?

Comment: Thank you @Mike i already set the log in the question?

Comment: having a quick look, there's a few weird things there. I think the key bit is the expired certificate, though. The admin console does 2-way SSL authentication with the DAS, so there could be a problem with your key/trust stores. Try getting your certificate updated first.

Comment: Thank @Mike, i don't use any certificate, i don't have any one? actually i work with PAYARA, it work fine with me

Comment: I think the only solution now, is to change my OS, i have 1 month with this problem, it make me crazy

Comment: In that case, this probably just the built-in GlassFish 3 key/truststores being out of date. GF 3.x is very old now! ;) so a solution would be to copy the keystore and cacerts from GlassFish 4.1.1 or Payara Server to your GF 3.1.2 domain in the domains config folder (replacing the ones in there). If I'm right about the problem, that would probably work.

Comment: thank you @Mike i will try to do it and i will inform you.

Comment: @Mike, i replace the two files but its not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ulises Fasoli's blog has a [great tutorial for glassfish admin password](http://ufasoli.blogspot.com/2013/07/glassfish-asadmin-without-password.html). Please check the following procedure:

If like me you hate having to type your user/password combination every-time that you run the asadmin utility command you have 2 options

1. Creating a password file and then using the --user --passwordfile options everytime you execute an asadmin command (ugh...)
2. Using the asadmin login command and never think about your password again
   Here's how you could implement both solutions :

### 1. Creating the password file

First you will need to create a file following the directives that can be found here[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4495/ghytn/index.html]

```
AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=mypassword
AS_ADMIN_USERPASSWORD=mypassword
AS_ADMIN_ALIASPASSWORD=mypassword


${glassfish_install}/glassfish/bin/asadmin  --user admin --passwordfile ${glassfish_install}/glassfish-password.txt list-applications mydomain
```

Now even though this works perfectly I find it a bit of a nag to have to write all this every-time I want to execute an asadmin command and sure I could write a bash script that wraps the underlying asadmin tool with the --user and --passwordfile options pre-generated but I just don't want to

### 2. Using the asadmin login command

The one I prefer though is using the asadmin login command.

Basically what this command does is it prompts you for your glassfish credentials and then stores them in an encrypted file (.asadminpass) under the user's home folder

### Here is how to use it :

> ```
> ${glassfish_install}/glassfish/bin/asadmin login 
> Enter admin user name [default: admin]> admin
> Enter admin password>
> Login information relevant to admin user name [admin]
> for host [localhost] and admin port [4848] stored at
> [/home/user/.asadminpass] successfully.
> Make sure that this file remains protected.
> ```

Once this is done you will be able to execute asadmin commands without being prompted for a password

> ```
> ${glassfish_install}/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
> Nothing to list.
> Command list-applications executed successfully.
> ```

You can even store remote glassfish instances password by using the --host flag with the login command

> ```
> [arte@arte-epg-api2 .ssh]$ /data/glassfish/bin/asadmin login --host myremotehost.com
> Enter admin user name [default: admin]> admin
> Enter admin password>
> Login information relevant to admin user name [admin]
> for host [myremotehost.com] and admin port [4848] stored at
> [/home/user/.asadminpass] successfully.
> Make sure that this file remains protected.
> ```

Comment: this work fine in command prompt but the problem is the Administration Console.

Comment: @YoucefLaidani For Administration Console, you need to do some extra jobs. It is described details here: http://logicoy.com/blogs/instructions-for-using-ldap-for-authenticating-admin/ . Please check.

Comment: i don't use LDAP, this solution not really help me!

Comment: Your two answers deserve the bounty @SkyWalker, thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2):

### Suggestion#1:

In oracle Community Handat told about reset/remove password:

> The password.txt file is user created so if you didn't create one for
>   autostart then there won't be such a file. To reset the password, or
>   remove it, there is a file in the config directory called
>   admin-keyfile. You can hash a known password with SSHA256 and replace
>   the one in there or remove the hashed password (between ; ;)
>   altogether to have no password.

Resource Link:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2403904

### Suggestion#2:

[Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341091/martin) suggested that

The problem is that the admin user is:

```
--user anonymous
```

no where documented. I only found it in the  config/admin-keyfile. The password then is indeed empty as vkraemer suggested:

```
AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=
```

### Resource Link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212765/2293534

### Suggestion#3:

If you use Netbeans then please check for password:

> Netbeans - > Services - > Glassfish -> Properties -> Password show?

### Information#1:

In [glassfish administration guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf), it is written as

> Note: For the zip bundle of GlassFish Server 4.0, the default
>   administrator login is admin, with no password, which means that no
>   login is required.

Resource Link:
https://askubuntu.com/a/526232

Comment: Thank you @SkyWalker for your answer, i tryed all what you do in the answer one and two, but nothing, same error, i can give you another information if i do deploy with command prompt every my application is deploy and i work normally, maybe this make sense thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @YoucefLaidani For Administration Console, you need to do some extra jobs. It is described details here: http://logicoy.com/blogs/instructions-for-using-ldap-for-authenticating-admin/ . Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the admin password via console/cmd with:

```
asadmin change-admin-password
```

Respond to the prompts - you must set a non-empty new password for GlassFish to accept the next command.

```
asadmin enable-secure-admin
asadmin restart-domain
```

Suggestion taken from [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18063?focusedCommentId=331152&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-331152)

Also, have you tried another jdk version?  If possible try uninstalling 1.7.0 and try an earlier version.  If no luck with an earlier jdk, try a more recent.

Try going to `'glassfish-install-path/domains/domain-name/config/admin-keyfile code`

(domain-name is the name of your domain, default should be domain1)

Open the admin-keyfile in Notepad, it should show a hashed value of the password (with the hashing algorithm used).  Try picking a new password, hashing it using the same algortithm, then copying/pasting into the admin-keyfile, save and try logging into console with the new password (plain text obviously) you pasted in the file.

Comment: i do all what you said @FanOfSkynyrd but this also not work with me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and gained back control by creating a password file in the installation folder containing a one liner:

```
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=your-password
```

After this execute the following commands:

```
asadmin --user admin --pssswordfile paaswd.txt

asadmin stop-domain

asadmin start-domain
```